# Is it possible to use Fabric Answers in an iOS App's dependent dynamic framework?

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric, fabric.io, google-fabric

I have `MyApp` iOS app with a dependent framework `MyAppServices.framework` built in Xcode. I would like to use `Fabric Answers`, via `Crashlytics` to send `Custom Events` to the Answers service.

I linked my both `MyApp` and `MyAppServices.framework` with the `Fabric` and `Crashlytics` frameworks, and it builds fine, however, although `Crashlytics` is sending information to the web service, no calls to `Answers.logCustomEvent` are received.

On app start up I get a number of messages taking this form in the console:

> objc[26265]: Class Answers is implemented in both /Users/daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dcrkrnbsowaakndgbzerrmisdgbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyAppServices.framework/MyAppServices (0x10fea9488) and /Users/danielasher/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E00AEB21-599A-4FDF-B97B-56CEE56963EC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/326C84A8-1CC9-4F75-86AF-253C98580A07/MyApp.app/MyApp (0x10f752ea8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

How can I successfully integrate Fabric Answers to my project?

Comment: Either your app or your framework can only implement Fabric, so which one? If your app is the source for Fabric, your lib will crash if the app dont have it, and if both app and framework have Fabric, it will result error like in yours

Comment: Have you installed Fabrics using Cocoapod?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Are you linking Fabric into the framework? If you do that instead of copying it in, you should be all set.

Comment: @Kampai I used the Fabric application (on OSX)

Comment: Yes it is required but what about Xcode project I mean you need to add Fabric API to iOS project, there are two way: You can manually add or using cocoapods. So I am asking how you integrated Fabric?

Comment: @Kampai I manually added `Fabric` and `Crashlytics` frameworks to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` and added the `Run Script` to `Build Phases` for `MyApp` and then manually added the frameworks to `Linked ...` for `MyAppServices` AND added `../MyApp` to `Framework Search Paths` in Build Settings